# Jquery Hidden selector or the remove attribute Halting the safari Browser

Tags: jquery, safari

Following is the code which is halting the process of Safari.

```
$( '.fields').find( ":hidden" ).remove( );
```

how can i get this as i want to remove the hidden fields before submitting the form. Where `.fields` is the class name of a div having the hidden fields.

Comment: Are you sure this is the issue ? Cause this seems quite straight forward and should work...

Comment: yeah buddy when i remove this code it just work like charm on safari. Although it works on every other browser.